# Md-select value not changing after select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, md-select

I have a problem with a md-select component using Angular and Angular Material 2. When I change the value of select it works, but the value of the md-select stays the same, which in my case is the default selected option "LTC". I need to show the current selected option and not the default selected option.
Thanks for your help!

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-allcoins',
  templateUrl: './allcoins.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./allcoins.component.scss']
})
export class AllcoinsComponent implements OnInit {

  regTypeSelectedOption: string = "LTC";
  selectedNav: any; 
  navs = ['LTC', 'ETH', 'ZEC', 'XRP']

  constructor() { }

  setNav(nav:any){
    this.selectedNav = nav;
        if(this.selectedNav == "LTC"){
            this.regTypeSelectedOption = "LTC";
        }
        else if(this.selectedNav == "ETH"){
            this.regTypeSelectedOption = "ETH";
        }
        else if(this.selectedNav == "ZEC"){
            this.regTypeSelectedOption = "ZEC";
        }
        else if(this.selectedNav == "XRP"){
          this.regTypeSelectedOption = "XRP";
      }
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedNav = 'select value';
  }

}
```

html

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header card-header-text">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Comprar Criptodivisas</h4>
                        <p class="category">Seleccione la criptodivisa que desea comprar</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <md-select placeholder="Moneda" [(ngModel)]="regTypeSelectedOption">
                            <md-option [value]="regTypeSelectedOption" (click)="setNav(item)" *ngFor="let item of navs">{{item}}</md-option>
                        </md-select>
                        <app-comprarzec *ngIf="regTypeSelectedOption === 'ZEC'"></app-comprarzec>
                        <app-comprarxrp *ngIf="regTypeSelectedOption === 'XRP'"></app-comprarxrp>
                        <app-comprarltc *ngIf="regTypeSelectedOption === 'LTC'"></app-comprarltc>
                        <app-comprareth *ngIf="regTypeSelectedOption === 'ETH'"></app-comprareth>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the change event on this case `(change)=""` it will let you controll every time a new option is selected so it will fire the event.

For your problem, you are telling that all values are `[value]="regTypeSelectedOption"` and you specified that it is "LTC" as default, you only need to use `regTypeSelectedOption` at NgModel, but not on the value.

**EDIT**

In your case (As you can see the value of the md-options equals to the item):

```
<md-option [value]="item" (click)="setNav(item)" *ngFor="let item of navs">{{item}}</md-option>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Manel, but could you be more specific please? Im just learning

Comment: Thank you Manel, it worked even though you didn't use `(change)=" "`